# Почему в React пишется вот так функция без фигурных скобок

Tags: javascript, reactjs

почему в React пишется вот так метод 
`comments.map( value => <li key={value.id}><Comment comment={value} /></li> )`

а вот так не работает

```
comments.map( value => {<li key={value.id}><Comment comment={value} /></li>} )
```

Comment: потому что [синтаксис JSX](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html). Ну и второй вариант может сработать при добавлении `return` внутрь скобок: `{return <li ...`

Comment: Тут скорее потому что стрелочные функции